# Windows authentication with HttpWebRequest in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, httpwebrequest, ntlm

I am creating an multi upload control in silverlight (we are using IE<9 so I cannot use file API).

I am using:

- Silverlight4 (http client stack)
- MVC4 (windows authentication, NTLM in DEV, kerberos in production)

I am trying to authenticate with the user using the current users credentials but I can't seem to reliably authenticate. Sometimes the request will push through, but most of the time it will fail with a 401 error.

Here's a code snippet:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp.Create(new Uri(uri));
request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = false; // <-- this enables upload progress reporting!
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + temp; // Boundary only needed for multipart form ada
request.ContentLength = (Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(_boundary) * 2) + _file.Descriptor.Length + Encoding.UTF8.GetByteCount(_header + "--\r\n\r\n\r\n");
request.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(WriteToStreamCallback), request);
```

I disable write stream buffering so I can show the file upload progress.

Here's the auth information from fiddler. It seems like it never finishes the challenge

Request:

```
Authorization Header is present: NTLM
4E 54 4C 4D 53 53 50 00 01 00 00 00 07 82 08 A2  NTLMSSP.......¢
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
06 01 B1 1D 00 00 00 0F                          ..±.....        


-[NTLM Type1: Negotiation]------------------------------
Provider: NTLMSSP
Type: 1
OS Version: 6.1:7601
Flags:  0xa2088207
    Unicode supported in security buffer.
    OEM strings supported in security buffer.
    Request server's authentication realm included in Type2 reply.
    NTLM authentication.
    Negotiate Always Sign.
    Negotiate NTLM2 Key.
    Supports 56-bit encryption.
    Supports 128-bit encryption.
Domain_Offset: 0; Domain_Length: 0; Domain_Length2: 0
Host_Offset: 0; Host_Length: 0; Host_Length2: 0
Host: 
Domain: 
------------------------------------
```

Response:

```
No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present.

WWW-Authenticate Header is present: NTLM
4E 54 4C 4D 53 53 50 00 02 00 00 00 10 00 10 00  NTLMSSP.........
--truncated--            


-[NTLM Type2: Challenge]------------------------------
Provider: NTLMSSP
Type: 2
OS Version: 6.1:7601
Flags:  0xa2898205
    Unicode supported in security buffer.
    Request server's authentication realm included in Type2 reply.
    NTLM authentication.
    Negotiate Always Sign.
    Negotiate NTLM2 Key.
    Target Information block provided for use in calculation of the NTLMv2 response.
    Supports 56-bit encryption.
    Supports 128-bit encryption.
Challenge: 31 AD 21 F4 40 FF BF 75
------------------------------------
```